# reading properties in assembly via reflection

Tags: .net, vb.net, reflection

I have a self-generated code in one assembly which in some of the lines includes properties, I was wondering how can I retrieve them? Especially when that class is a view object and does not contain any parameters so we can do it by data adapter and finding for example insert or update parameter. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting properties of type:

```
Type someType = typeof(MyClass);
PropertyInfo[] properties = someType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy );
```

Getting types:

```
Assembly someAssembly = typeof(MyClass).Assembly;
Type[] typesInSomeAssembly = someAssembly.GetTypes();
```

Getting and setting value from property info:

```
MyClass cls = new MyClass();
PropertyInfo propText = cls.GetType().GetProperty("Text");
object valueOfTextProperty = propText.GetValue(cls, null);
propText.SetValue(cls, "New text", null);
```